# The most common way to refer to non-immediate family?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Example:

> When my mother came back from the island, she came back as a newborn Christian. [...]
>   was shocked, especially since none of them belonged to that religion.

(In this case, *they* refer to the mother's parents/brothers/sisters, and also the husband's parents/brothers/sisters. Not the husband because he was dead. And not the speaker because he was still a baby. So there's no immediate family.)

What would a native English speaker use in cases like this? *Her family, my family, our family, or my relatives*?

Comment: *"When my mother . . . her family and that of [**her late husband's**](https://www.google.it/search?q=her+family+and+that+of+her+late+husband%27s&oq=her+family+and+that+of+her+late+husband%27s&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=her+family+and+that+of+%22her+late+husband%27s%22) . . ."* is probably the most accurate but it's a bit of a mouthful. (click on the link to see how other authors have coped.)

Comment: A person's parents and siblings are normally considered to be their immediate family! So I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. A term to cover both your immediate family and your spouse's immediate family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say *relative*

> noun: relative; plural noun: relatives
>       - a person connected by blood or marriage.

When my mother came back from the island, she came back as a newborn Christian. [...] was shocked, especially since none of *her relatives* belonged to that religion.

Comment: How would you fit "relative" within the OP's sentence? (I'm tempted to upvote, but you need to be a little more precise). EDIT: What about the empty space?

Comment: Try "her relatives **and** in-laws".

Answer (score 1):

> Inlaws, extended family, clan, tribe.

In your case I would say extended family.